# info - unhandled socket.io url

Tags: exception, node.js, javascript-framework, socket.io

I working on a socket.io + node project.
Just like in this page, http://davidwalsh.name/websocket
I am getting "info - unhandled socket.io url" error in socket.io v7. But I dont get this error with v6.17? Do you have any idea with this error?

Thanks

Comment: A [quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q="info+-+unhandled+socket.io+url") of your error returned [this Socket.IO issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/279), created a couple months ago. Take a look through the whole thread and see if anything helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact issue couple of days back and looks like socket.io had some changes in the API.

I have a working demo of socket.io sending and receiving a message - uploaded to https://github.com/parj/node-websocket-demo as a reference

Essentially two changes

1. On Server side - changed `socket.on` to `socket.sockets.on`

   ```
   var socket = io.listen(server);
   socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client)
   ```
2. On Client side - URL and port not required as it is autodetected.

   ```
   var socket = io.connect();
   ```

NOTE: you can also `io.connect("http://<ip>:<port>")` on the client side, however, not required anymore as it is autodetected

Here are the exact changes - https://github.com/parj/node-websocket-demo/commit/5ba52db9d1a5b7e8a3af5839adcd12768741dc97

This has been tested using Express 2.5.2 and Socket.io 0.8.7